# 'xcorr' function in matlab not working for zero signal

Tags: matlab

I came across an interesting problem when using 'xcorr' in MATLAB. The expected signal and generated signal both are at zero DC. So, I expect correlation coefficient to be 1 or perfectly correlated. To my surprise, It is showing the highest error and time lag !!! Pls help !

Thanks,

Comment: According to the definition of xcorr the output should be zero at all lags for input vectors that are all zeros, and that is what I get when I put `X=zeros(1,10);Y=zeros(1,10)` and execure `[R,LAG]=xcorr(X,Y)`. Note `xcorr` is not producing the correlation coefficient unless you specifically ask it to, but then you will be dividing by zero and get `NaN` as a result..

Answer (score 1):

the xcorr function is defined as
$$R_{xy}(m)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-m-1}x_{n+m}y^*_n  & \mbox{if } m \geq 0 \\
  R^*_{yx}(-m)& \mbox{if } m < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
The output is given as $$c(m)=R_{xy}(m-N)$$ where N is the length of the signal by the above definition the output for zero signal is zero